# YouTube may disable your inactive project's access to the YouTube Data API Service

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I was using `Youtube Data API`to get youtube video but after getting mail from youtube which says api is disable due to inactive.

Youtube Data api not working since it was disabled by youtube because of inactive for 90 Days. I am not able to call(It is enable in API Console) it even with delete and add new delete back. Please help.

Error shows when i am calling from Web Browsers with api Key i also tried to generate new API key also delete and regenerate new api key but still no luck.

> "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project
>   264969722993 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=264969722993
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry."

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question as you. I'm in the same boat. Other than creating a new Google account (which would be very annoying) I'm not sure what else to do. I'll let you know if I ever find a solution to this issue.

Comment: YouTube API contact form has been moved to https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form.

Answer (score 4):

There are things you can do to try and solve this issue. This first option is to apply for an API exception by filling out this out [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5HxReFtxATJLNfLwQiucfQwYL295Xemgc6nhFXo1vcitg3A/viewform). I've filled out this form and am waiting for a response.

The second option is to create a new project and use that project to generate an API key. Because Google has only disabled access to the Youtube Data API for your current project, the new project's API key should work just fine. I've tried this and can confirm this works. This is probably the more hassle-free option if you have extra projects to spare as Google only allows 10 projects at any point in time.

Comment: New project api solution will work but i don't want to change my project cuz of billing credit

Comment: It's worth noticing that this could happen during development. I merely used my key to verify functionality, and then forgot about it for 90 days. Oops... Going for the second option!

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the same position, disabled for no calls in 90 days. You can request an exemption but after about 25 back and forth emails it's clear that it is just a smokescreen. After explaining what it's used for they then wanted screenshots, then videos of you using the application, how we use the videos we pull up, and then a shot of the room where it was being used. They even asked who made the video we were looking at (we have no idea!). They want your whole business model and what you do. It was just never ending questions and more stuff to send them. After about 2 1/2 months of slow back and forth, I get a message saying I am out of compliance.

Our application uses YouTube to pull up videos for manufacturers product for research and training in a small training/conference room for internal use only. That's all!
Nothing was out of compliance.

This is the email we received:

> Hello ,
>
> We have reviewed your quota extension request for project number
>
> #### and have revoked the allocated quota for your API Client(s) as it is out of compliance on the following YouTube API Services -
>
> Developer Policy:
>
> Policy F. 1 (User Experience - YouTube Look and Feel)  Please do not
>   reply to this email, you may complete and submit this form to re-apply
>   once the above concern has been addressed.
>
> Thanks, YouTube API Services team

The form link in the email is just a link to start the whole process over again.

Answer (score 0):

According to YouTube policy

If your API Client's quota is reduced or eliminated, you may reapply for quota or a quota extension, and YouTube will review that application based on YouTube’s determination of your expected use of the YouTube API Services.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies

I suggest reapplying.

Comment: My quota was never over used and its was just because of inactive.

Answer (score 0):

To add to *avatarhzh*'s answer:

If you have already used up your initial cap of max. 12 projects and your channel is a **brand account** and you do not want to go through the process of applying for more quota/getting back your previous quota, you can also create new projects on a different google account and then add that account to your channel [as a manager](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4628007). It is then possible to access your channel through this new account via the youtube data API.

If your channel is not a brand account yet, you can [move your channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3056283?hl=en) to a brand account. This allows you to add different google accounts as managers/co-owners of the channel. *Warning: certain things (e.g. comments) cannot be transferred when moving to a brand account.*