# Sudden problems with Youtube Data API authentication and quota error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-data-api

Last year I was building an application to create my own YT dashboard.
It was based only the [code](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbWpPMFV2NEtsSW5ja2swbWJzSGxxUU9lbVBBZ3xBQ3Jtc0tsRDFyTXlfLWNmZXhGOTV0RE1VVENKMGtJRXlPZ0E0VXZfTG41Wi0wMmtyZmx6bmN2THA2RkFkQ2NoSmp6Tno2eTVsWDNEdEh3QVBBdElUVzFFR1FSTVJSS25HV1R2QUEyRVl1MkwzTXJwU0stTk90OA&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fbradtraversy%2Fyoutube_api_auth_app) of a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-yxNNO1EI8)
They basically authenticate a user via OAuth and send requests to get channel data or playlists of the authenticated user.

I was trying out both the original tutorial app and my own (after a few dormant months) and they suddenly don't work anymore.
Meaning: I can authenticate on both, but on the original version I get a [403 error](https://content-youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername=techguyweb&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics) telling me: "The request is missing a valid API key." (on requesting channel data)

This is confusing because the API key is never used because only the OAuth client id was necessary.

And on my own fancy version, I get a 403 error telling me that I've exceeded my getting started quota. (on requesting the users playlists)

Looking at my quota page:
[image]

I can see, that queries per day (why is it there twice?) is somehow set to 0.

Perhaps creating a new OAuth 2.0 Client ID or a new API key would solve these errors, as was suggested in another post.

But since I'm planning to use the YT Data API in a real project soon and want to prevent this from ever happening I would like to understand what was going on. Why the daily quota limit is suddenly turned to 0 and how to go about it when that happens.
Or at least how to contact google about it.

Perhaps some of you have some insights.

UPDATE:
I've just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620912/youtube-may-disable-your-inactive-projects-access-to-the-youtube-data-api-servi?rq=1) reporting, that after 90 inactive days, the quota is automatically set to 0.
Now I created a new OAuth Client Id and replaced the constant in my code. Nothing changed so far. Perhaps I have to wait 24h. Or perhaps I have to fill out [this form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) which apparently can lead to months of back and forth email nonsense. I sure hope not.

Comment: Google disabled your project [due to inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63211212/8327971).

Comment: Please make sure that you're currently using the JSON client secrets file associated to the newly created project. Do post your code, though, if needing more help.

Comment: Thanks. Does this change, if I don't use OAuth and only request public playlists?

Comment: regarding the JSON client secrets file: I could not find any guide on how to add this to my code. Does it have to be listed under: 
gapi.client
    .init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES
        
    })

Comment: I see you're using GAPI on a client-side web app (right?). Then the `client_secret` info is not needed, but the `client_id` is. Your call to `gapi.client.init` looks OK.

Comment: If it was necessary I would just add clientSecret: as a key with the secret JSON (unstringed) as a value, right?

-
Anyway, I just realized I had to enable the YT Data API for the newly created project. I'll add that to my official answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230938/discussion-between-mr-goat-and-stvar).

Comment: Sorry, for being unintentionally too brief: the `client_secret` info is contained within the JSON client secrets file downloaded from the developers console. Client-side web apps do not use that JSON file per se (but other type of apps using the API do).

Answer (score 1):

It seemed the only viable option was to create a new project with new credentials.
(And one should not forget that the YT Data API has to be enabled again for the new project.)